# What does it mean to "check code into GitHub"?

Tags: python, django, github

"So you’d make the migrations in developement environment, you get them right, and then you’d like check them into GitHub, perhaps. And then in production, you would pull your migrations out of GitHub and then they’ll migrate."

So I'm listening to a lecture right now and it says this. It's in regards to models and migrations. I'm new so the only thing I know about GitHub is basically to store your projects etc. What do they mean by "then if you'd like check them into GitHub" perhaps.

And then pull your migrations out of GitHub and then they'll migrate. Can someone explain in Fortnite terms please. Thank you. Just a newby trying to understand. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not the place to ask this question. Try with a forum

Comment: If not, then where is?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your post, "checking into GitHub" means pushing your changes/migrations from your local repository to the remote repository in GitHub. Once you do that you can pull your changes/migrations in production.

I hope this helps. If it is still unclear, I would suggest FreeCodeCamp's [Git and Github Tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-and-github-for-beginners/) to understand the version control system better.

Comment: I've taken a python class and studying Django right now and it doesn't have anything in regards to GitHub. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer is helpful please upvote and accept the answer! Hope you have a fantastic time learning Django and all the cool tricks and tips of the software development world.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest way it means this:

You have code on your computer (called local). You need to copy (check) that code to github.com (called remote).

To do it, you need to do 3 operations, called "stage", "commit", "push".

At the end of this process, your code will be copied to git.